# How do I add a query parameter to a URL?

Tags: url, parameters, tritium, moovweb

What's the best practice for adding a query parameter to a URL in Tritium (Moovweb SDK)? Looking for something that works where you don't know if the URL has a "?" and other query parameters already.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short snippet of Tritium that should help you out in your Moovweb project. Just replace the **"query_param=true"** bit with the query parameter you want to add.

It selects the `href` of every `a` tag, then looks for any existing query parameters (by looking for a "?" in the href). If there are some existing, it just appends the new query parameter. If there are no existing query parameters on the href, it uses the ? to add one to the URL.

```
$q = "query_param=true"
$("//a[@href]") {
  %s = fetch("./@href")
  match(%s) {
    with(/\?/) {
      attribute("href", %s + "&" + $q)
    }
    else() {
      attribute("href", %s + "?" + $q)
    } 
  }
log(%s) 
}
```

(You could also turn that into a function if you wanted!)

Comment: This is one of the first questions someone coming the platform asks. It's worth reading the tritium spec for [fetch](http://tritium.io/simple-mobile/1.0.188#Node.fetch(Text%20%25selector)%20Text%20Text).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is going to be a new URL scope soon so you'll be able to do things like this much more easily!